# Show that $P(X>t)\leq \frac{E(e^{cX})}{e^{ct}}$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose $X$ is a random variable and $c$ is a constant. Show that $$P(X>t)\leq \frac{E(e^{cX})}{e^{ct}}.$$

I about thought using Markov's inequality that for nonnegative random variable $X$ and $c>0$ we have $P(X\geq c)\leq\frac{E(X)}{c}$.

But here I don't know if $X$ and $c$ are nonnegative. I don't know how to solve this. Would you please help?

Comment: The exponential function is an increasing bijection and you want to replace $X$ by $e^{cX}$...

Comment: Right, $P(X>t)=P\left(e^{cX}>e^{ct}\right),$ at least when $c>0.$ You’ll need a separate argument for $c<0$ and $c=0.$

Comment: (I’m not immediately convinced this is true for $c<0.$)

Comment: Why you have deleted your [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350203/variance-of-geometric-distribution-without-replacement) ?

Comment: @callculus42 You were right. I thought the probability function must be something complicated like the probability function of Negative Binomial. But it was just $1/n$. So I could solve it easily with your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Lucy OK. Since the distribution is simpler than at the first  glance the question is quiet interesting, it would be better not to delete the question-in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim isn't true for $c<0$. For example, let $X$ be uniform (0,1), $c=-10$ and $t=1/c$.

For $c=0$, the claim is trivial. For $c>0$, we have:
$$
\Big[X>t\iff\exp(cX)>\exp(ct)\Big]\implies\Pr(X>t)=\Pr[\exp(cX)>\exp(ct)]
$$
Now use Markov's inequality with $Y=\exp(cX)$.

Comment: In Markov's inequality, we have $\geq$. But here we have $>$. How can I use Markov's inequality?

Comment: $\Pr(Y>y)\leq \Pr(Y\geq y)$ because $Y>y$ implies $Y\geq y$.